# Running jspc maven plugin on a GWT project structure

Tags: jsp, gwt, maven-2

My GWT based web application follows the GWT project structure much like as described in

[GWT Standard Directory and Package Layout](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html)

The project has few JSP's in the project and I wanted to use the JSPC plugin to pre-compile and package them.

I have added the maven plugin as

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jspc-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>jspc</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <warSourceDirectory>${basedir}/war</warSourceDirectory>                         
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <webappDirectory>${gwt.output.directory}</webappDirectory>
                ....

                <webXml>${basedir}/target/jspweb.xml</webXml>   
                <injectString>&lt;!-- [INSERT FRAGMENT HERE] --&gt;</injectString>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

But while running it, I get the following error

```
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:jspc-maven-plugin:1.4.6:compile (jspc) on project fqng-webapp: JSPC Error: C:\MyWorkSpace\XXX\YYYY\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml (The system cannot find the path specified) -> [Help 1]
```

It seems JSP Compiler is looking for web.xml based on a maven webapp structure. Is there a way to configure the JSPC plugin to work with GWT project structure?

Comment: We have JSP file in our GWT project and we do not pre-compile it. It is as is in the war file. Any reason for you to choose pre-compilation?